# Error while adding columns to SQLite3 database table using python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in SQLite database using a list of items in python but while creating a table it is giving me an operational error.

I am using a python for loop to use this list items as column headers. The loop was working fine till list item 'QT' and after that it is breaking and giving me the error.

```
col_names = [
    "ABPs",
    "ABPd",
    "ABPm",
    "ARTs",
    "ARTd",
    "ARTm",
    "AoS",
    "AoD",
    "AoM",
    "UAPs",
    "UAPd",
    "UAPm",
    "P1s",
    "P1d",
    "P1m",
    "NBPs",
    "NBPd",
    "NBPm",
    "P_1d",
    "P_1m",
    "PVC",
    "QT",
    "QT-HR",
    "QTc",
    "ST-I",
    "ST-II",
    "ST-III",
    "ST-aVR",
    "ST-aVF",
    "ST-aVL",
    "ST-MCL",
    "ST-V1",
    "ST-V2",
    "dQTc",
    "ST-V3",
    "ST-V4",
    "ST-V5",
    "ST-V6",
]

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE CICU2 (datetime DATETIME)""")
for colname in col_names:
    cur.execute("""ALTER TABLE CICU2 ADD COLUMN """ + colname + """ TEXT""")
```

Error : `near "-": syntax error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` is not permitted in unescaped column names; you are asking SQLite to subtract one column name from another. You must use [proper quoting](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) if you want to use any non-standard characters in a column name.

The standard method of quoting a column name is to use double quotes; any existing double quotes in a column name can be replaced with *doubled* double quotes:

```
cur.execute('ALTER TABLE CICU2 ADD COLUMN "{}" TEXT'.format(colname.replace('"', '""'))
```

I used a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to insert the column name into the query, which is easier to read for humans. The `{}` part is replaced by the value of the first argument to the `str.format()` method.